# How to find the equation for the line $t$, in the plane $\pi$ and concurrent to other 2 lines

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, analytic-geometry

The exercise says that $t$ is in the plane $\pi: x-y+z =0$ and is concurrent to the lines:

$$r:\\x+y+2z=2\\x=y$$

and 
$$s:\\z=x+2\\y=0$$

I've transformed $r$ to the form:

$$r:\\x = \lambda\\ y = \lambda\\ z = 1-\lambda$$

and $$s:\\x = t\\y = 0\\z = t+2$$

Then the vector $$\vec {PQ}$$ from line $r$ to $s$ is:

$$(t-\lambda, -\lambda, t+1+\lambda)$$

Since the line is contained in the plane, $\vec {PQ}$ must be orthogonal to the normal $$\vec n = (1,-1,1)$$ and therefore:

$$(t-\lambda, -\lambda, t+1+\lambda)\cdot(1,-1,1) = 0$$

But I can't solve after this because I'm left with $t$ and $\lambda$.
Please help me, I'm really trying :(

Comment: There isn't going to be a unique line $t$, there are many lines in a particular plane passing though a particular point. Are there any other conditions on $t$?

Comment: @MikeEarnest there's no more information, and the answer is an unique line :(

Comment: But you see my point, right? Saying that $t$ is concurrent to two other lines is just saying that $t$ passes through their intersection. Even when $t$ is constrained to be in $\pi$, it is still free to rotate. However, to find _a_ line $t$ which works, I would start by finding the point where $r$ and $s$ intersect, then find a vector perpendicular to $\vec n$.

Comment: @MikeEarnest I know that it is free to rotate, but maybe those two points of intersection in the lines are not in the plane $\pi$, so they're not free to rotate

Comment: @MikeEarnest: I thought the same, but $r$ and $s$ don't intersect: from $s$ you have $y=0$ which you plug into $r$ to get $x=y=0$, in which case you get $z=1$ from $r$ but $z=2$ from $s$. No intersection, therefore no *three* concurrent lines. Therefore I assume the question was about pairwise concurrent lines.

Comment: Ah, I see now. Sorry for the confusion, @GuerlandoOCs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line $t$ you are looking for

- should lie in $\pi$
- should intersect $r$
- should intersect $s$

Therefore I'd check where $r$ resp. $s$ intersect $\pi$. The line connecting these points would be $t$.